# Query with values that have special characters

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document with following structure:

```
{
    "_index": "logstash-2014.10.08",
    "_type": "iis",
    "_id": "HRM7LWfBSPGo9PUS0Z1ynw",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "@version": "1",
        "@timestamp": "2014-10-08T12:37:26.000Z",
        "type": "iis",
        "messageId": 
  "O5pUHWOuEnTT0xQxXfNW6L+O6EMIjTFO7e//t+S/99en4zzOnlhqjEKlw02ZZVRFlyVaawA=="
    }
}
```

Here is my mapping:

```
      "messageId" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "norms" : {
          "enabled" : false
        },
        "fields" : {
          "raw" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      }
```

I'm trying to perform a query and i would like to return only the documents that have the exact value of messageId that is passed on query. I've tried to perform queries using match and filter.

If i use term, it returns zero documents:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term" : {
        "messageId" : 
      "O5pUHWOuEnTT0xQxXfNW6L+O6EMIjTFO7e//t+S/99en4zzOnlhqjEKlw02ZZVRFlyVaawA=="
        }
    }
}
```

When i use match, i can get my document back but if i do little changes on messageId, it still returns my document and the messageId on query is different from the document.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match" : {
        "messageId" : 
             "O5pUHWOuxXfNW6L+O6EMIjTFO7e//t+S/99en4zzOnlhqjEKlw02ZZVRFlyVaawA=="
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone knows how can i do a query and retrieve the documents that have exact value for messageId?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Can you add the cURL commands to recreate it?  I don't think your mapping is being applied at index time.  You could try the test field analyzer to ensure it's being indexed as one token.

Comment: I've indexed it using Logstash. How can i use field analyzer?

Comment: I'm not familiar with norms around Logstash,  does your index get configured automatically?  Test the field analyzer using cURL command @ http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is a special character problem, instead I think it is an index analyzed vs non-analyzed problem.  If you use a regular, analyzed field you need to search for everything in lower-case to get a term match.  For not-analyzed that is not the case.

I ran the following test using your sample and I was able to get the result back that you wanted.

```
PUT index1

PUT index1/type1/_mapping
{
  "type1": {
    "properties": {
      "raw" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
    }
  }
}

POST index1/type1
{
  "raw": "O5pUHWOuEnTT0xQxXfNW6L+O6EMIjTFO7e//t+S/99en4zzOnlhqjEKlw02ZZVRFlyVaawA=="
}

GET index1/type1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "raw": {
        "value": "O5pUHWOuEnTT0xQxXfNW6L+O6EMIjTFO7e//t+S/99en4zzOnlhqjEKlw02ZZVRFlyVaawA=="
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My guess is that the data in the field you are working on is analyzed.  You can check this by getting the using the _mapping API.  In my example that would be:

```
GET index1/type1/_mapping
```